# Print value from a function. React-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a problem about how to print a value,in a function,  in react-native.

Basically I have a function that research in the DB some values, and I should print this values.

```
findUtente(cf) {
    let params = {};
    console.log(cf)
    params = {
      "Person.FiscalCode": cf
    };
    global.utente.db.localdb().find({
        selector: params
      })
      .then(response => {
          let utente = response.docs[0];
          console.log ("utente: " + utente)
          utente.Person.FirstName;
          console.log ("utente.Person.FirstName: " + utente.Person.FirstName)
        })
        //.... catch...}); }
render() {
   {this.findUtente(this.props.cf)}
return (
      <View style={style.container}>
        <View style={style.page}>
          <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
            <Text style={visualProfilo.text}>Name:</Text>
            <Text style={visualProfilo.text1}>{Stamp Here the FirstName}</Text>
```

The value in the console log is print in the right way.
How can I print that value?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `componentDidMount` to call the method then you can set the value to state and then update value using setState then render state value
example:

```
state = {
   FirstName: ''
}
componentDidMount(){
  this.findUtente(this.props.cf)
}

findUtente(cf) {
    let params = {};
    console.log(cf)
    params = {
      "Person.FiscalCode": cf
    };
    global.utente.db.localdb().find({
        selector: params
      })
      .then(response => {
          let utente = response.docs[0];
          this.setState({FirstName: utente.Person.FirstName})
        })
        //.... catch...}); }
render() {
  return (
   //everything remains same
   <Text style={visualProfilo.text1}>{this.state.FirstName}</Text>
  )
}
```

Comment: And How can I print the value in the rendere () { return ??

Comment: Why do want to print on the render function ??

Comment: I would to print the value where I wrote {Stamp Here the FirstName}

Comment: It's works!! Thank you so much! (Only last question, I should call componentWillUnmount() ???

Comment: No need to call `componentWillUnmount`.